# How do I force Latex to use the default vector typesetting?

Tags: vector

I am using the ubcdiss.cls document format for my thesis from https://github.com/briandealwis/ubcdiss

Unfortunately, it automatically causes vectors to render as bold rather than with an over-arrow.

I have tried looking for a redefinition for the `\vec` command in the associated files, but could not find one.

Are there any packages that may be changing the Latex default?

Alternatively, how can I force Latex to return to its default behaviour for the `\vec` command?

Comment: Please post a minimal, but complete code which reproduces the problem. B.t.w., the `esvect` package defines much nicer vector arrows than the standard  `\vec` (it uses a `\vv` command instead).

Comment: If I download a ZIP file of the linked GitHub site and add `$\vec{x}$` just after `\begin{document}`, I get the standard arrow over the x.

Comment: @egreg Interesting. Maybe it is something else I have in the file. Anyway, `\renewcommand` worked.

Comment: @Bernard I will look into the `esvect` package for future documents; I hadn't realised before `\vec` stopped working that there was a better way. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restore the default definition of `\vec` using

```
\renewcommand*\vec{\mathaccent"017E\relax}
```

Comment: I do think that the bold notation is generally preferable, though.

Comment: Do you know the `\vv` command from `esvect`?

Comment: @Bernard I didn't. The reason why I dislike the arrow notation is not solved by that package, though. I just think that the real estate above a symbol is far to valuable just for "btw. this symbol denotes a vector"; there is a multitude of notations that also use this space (e.g. `\tilde`, `\bar`, `\hat`) that don't mix well with an arrow.

Comment: Thank you! That `\renewcommand` worked when I put it just after `\begin{document}`. I am incorporating a paper into the text that uses a bold font to represent matrices and an over-arrow to represent vectors, so having them both in bold was confusing in places.

Comment: Or use  `\let\vec=\vv`.  I prefer the arrow vector for physics and the bold vector for matrices.